# Is it possible to attach a pdf in android app for offline viewing?

Tags: android, pdf

I'm trying to attach a PDF file within my android application as part of the application, that gets downloaded when the user downloads the app. Is is possible to do that? I already know about opening a pdf with webview in my app, but I want to know how to attach the pdf file with my app so that it can be viewed offline.
Please let me know if this is possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your PDF has small size, you can put it in assets folder, so user can view it right after installing app, even without network connection. If it has big size, you can share it in the cloud (e.g. dropbox) and later download it and save to device's internal storage.

[Using the Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

Comment: Could you please tell me what should be ideal size or size range of the pdf file, if I want to include it in the assets folder ? My file is of around 4-5 mb